# how to trigger onclicksubmit event in jqgrid manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

how to trigger `onclicksubmit` event in **`jqgrid`** manually?

I have a condition ,if it is true I want to call the submit event manually.  Please take a look at the code.

```
afterShowForm: function (formid) {
    if (condition) {
        jQuery("#editmodgrid").trigger('submit');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button with the text "Submit" of the form editing is not a submit button. It is `<a>` element which has id="sData". So to simulate `click` on the button you can do the following

```js
afterShowForm: function () {
    if (condition) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sData").click();
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

or the following

```js
afterShowForm: function ($form) {
    if (condition) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $form.next(".EditTable").find("#sData").click();
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClickInsideOfAfterShowForm.htm) demonstrate the above code.

Comment: @user2954936: One have to use `click` (trigger("click")) inside of `setTimeout` because jqGrid make binding to `click` event *after* calling of `afterShowForm`. I updated my answer and included demo in it.